# how to get the day after selected day with php or javascript?

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I'm using JQuery datepicker to allow user select a day and book something.
then I save the date in database,
later on I get the dates out of database and disable those days in datapicker so next user can't select the booked days.
so far so good.

when a user select the day they want to book I need to disable the day after too.
I'm using php to save the chosen date in database together with some other information about user.
then i use ajax to load the dates thru php again and disable them.

how can i disable the they after? do I do it with php or javascript?
I have no idea how to get the day after selected date and how to save it? or should i save it or just add it later on when I get back the first date from ajax call and then loop thru the dates and get the day after with some function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use PHP if you can by simply returning a list of dates to the `beforeShowDay` method of your DatePicker.

When you are adding a date from the database to the list, also use `strtotime($Date, '1 day')` to add the next day.

Edit:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT distinct Date, DATE_ADD(Date, INTERVAL 31 DAY) as Tomorrow from Table";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$Dates = array();

/* numeric array */
while(($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) !== null)
{
    //$Tomorrow = strtotime('1 day', $row['Date']);
    $Tomorrow = $row['Tomorrow'];
    if(!in_array($row['Date'], $Dates)) $Dates[] = $row['Date'];
    if(!in_array($Tomorrow, $Dates)) $Dates[] = $Tomorrow;
}
/* free result set */
$result->free();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

header('content-type: application/json');
die(json_encode(array('Dates' => $Dates)));
```

Comment: yes i know how to disable the days using beforeShowDay.i just needed the strtotime($Date, '1 day'), going to test it now..

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHPs [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function:

`strtotime("+1 day", $reservationDate)`

Answer (score 0):

You can call any javascript function `onSelect` of datepicker

for just an example

`onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
                        //dateFormat: 'DD, MM d, yy'
                        var theDate = $(inst).datepicker.formatDate('DD, MM d, yy', $(inst).datepicker.('getDate'));
                        $("#temp_date_start").text(theDate);
                    }`

Answer (score 0):

If I would have to solve this problem. I would do this by sending one date to PHP (from JavaScript) and then use PHP to add both dates to the database. So I would use the PHP date functionality to get the next day (for example with http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php). This because working with dates in JQuery isn't as easy as in PHP, but it's not because it isn't easy that it is impossible of course :-)

But if you want to use the functionality in real time. So for example if you don't have a page refresh between clicking on the selected date and disabling those dates. In that case I would suggest that your PHP background call returns the dates to disable (or the ids of the elements or something like that).

tl;dr: Send one date to PHP, use PHP date functions to get next day, save both dates in your database

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#elementID").datepicker({
       onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
          var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');  //get selectedDate
              minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate()+1);     //adds one day to minDate
          //do whatever you do to disable the date using "minDate"
       }
});
```